# how to get userintraction in uiwebview when added as sub view on a button in ios

Tags: uiwebview

I have a button performs some action, have added uiwebview as a sub view of the button to load a small gif animation, I can tap the button to perform the task but I needed to perform the same action when I tap the web view.

```
-(void)numeritsIphone4{
    arrayButtonNames = @[@"Button1.png",@"Button2",@"Button3",@"Button4",@"Button5.png",@"Button6.png",@"Button7.png",@"Button8.png",@"Button9.png",@"Button10.png"];


    float y = 20;
    int x = 3;
    int count = 0;

       for (int i = 0 ; i < 10; i++)
    {
        count ++;

        buttonsarray[i] = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
        buttonsarray[i].frame =  CGRectMake(x, y, 155, 90);
        buttonsarray[i].tag = i;
        [buttonsarray[i] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[arrayButtonNames objectAtIndex:i]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];


        [buttonsarray[i].titleLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Verdana"  size:80]];
        [buttonsarray[i] setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        //buttonsarray[i].titleLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
        buttonsarray[i].contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentCenter;
        [buttonsarray[i] setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",digit] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        digit ++;
        character = [[UIWebView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 30, 25, 25)];
        NSURL *url=[[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"Star" ofType:@"gif"]];
        character.opaque = NO;
        character.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        character.scrollView.scrollEnabled = NO;
        [character loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url]];
        character.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
        [buttonsarray[0] addSubview:character];
        [character release];
        [url release];
        [buttonsarray[i] addTarget:self action:@selector(performOperation4:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        x = x + 159;
        [self.view addSubview:buttonsarray[i]];
        if(count == 2)
        {
            count = 0;
            x = 3;
            y = y+ 92;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

A possibility is to add a `UITapGestureRecognizer` to your `UIWebView` control and call the same function when the gesture recognizes.

**NOTE:** This way you have limitation if you have some buttons, links etc on your UIWebView page, that button, links might not get trigger. So give it a try and see if it helps you.